# Multiple box with triangle on bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I'm fighting with css code to obtain something that should be pretty easy:
adding a triangle at the bottom of multiple div on the same page.

Here it's the code I'm working with:

```
.areatitolo {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5%;
    margin-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

.areatitolo:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #bb0000;
    border-left: solid 100px transparent;
    border-right: solid 100px transparent;
}
```

There shouldn't be any problem, apart from the fact that only the first one works and I need to use the same effect 3 times...
Do you know where I made the mistake?

https://jsfiddle.net/federico_feroldi/0zrfL4q1/4/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The position absolute positions all 3 triangles on top of each other

Comment: Add *position: relative;* to .areatitolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.areatitolo`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use position :relative to the class .areatitolo .Because you have used absolute for ::after. whenever you use position absolute to a child element ,you should use position relative to parent if not the absolute child will take body as relative parent by default ,thats why the first triangle appears at the top  all the other triangles get overlaped on top

Answer (score 0):

For a child element to be absolutely positioned, the parent must have a `position: relative;` property applied to it. This gives the child a reference point for it's positioning.

Additionally, consider using `::after` instead of `:after` for a more modern CSS3 syntax. [See MDN for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Syntax)